# Testing an webservice using Junit getting errors

Tags: java, web-services, junit, axis

I am testing a java webservice with client jar which is made by axis-ant,When i run the test i'm getting the following errors.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc.(Ljava/lang/Class;Z)V
    at com.xxxx.www.xxxx.xsd.GetSalesIdRequest.(Unknown Source)

Please help me.

Comment: Came across this blog, I wonder if it will be useful http://mcondev.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/mobile-application-testing-functionality-and-performance-junit-testsuite/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you haven not added apache axis to your classpath.